# Running command line program inside java program

Tags: java

Im trying to run a program that takes a long time to finish inside a java program. The program inside the java program outputs a huge file (somewhere between 4 to 6 GB). I use the following code inside the main method.

```
//get the runtime goinog
Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
//execute program
Process pr = rt.exec("theProgram.exe");
//wqit forprogram to finish
pr.waitFor();
```

I get a number of errors:

- when the java program ends theProgram.exe does not stop sometimes the
- java program never ends even when theProgram.exe has ended
- theProgram.exe stops without finishing, and the java program does not stop.

More information:

- I'm using cygwin in Windows7

Comment: Please explain what you mean by the `theProgram.exe` stops without finishing

Comment: I mean, I know the expected result because I have run it directly on the command line, but when i run it inside the java program sometimes it stops, and I dont see the same result. In these cases, the java program does not stop running

Comment: If the process has useful output to gauge its progress, try redirecting its output as I demonstrate in my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling this method with your `Process pr` will **terminate the process** when your java program exits:

```
private void attachShutdownHook(final Process process) {
    Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            process.destroy();
        }
    });
}
```

If your process has output you can use to assess its progress, then **redirect output** to java by calling:

```
private void redirectOutputStreamsToConsole(Process process) {
    redirectStream(process.getInputStream(), System.out);
    redirectStream(process.getErrorStream(), System.err);
}

private void redirectStream(final InputStream in, final PrintStream out) {
    new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
                String line = null;
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
                    out.println(line);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
        }
    }.start();
}
```

Comment: could I just add pr.destroy() at the end of the program?

Comment: This is preferable because most programs can have multiple exit points, for instance if it unexpectedly throws an `Exception` you will probably want to make sure the process terminates.

Comment: this worked great, now what should I change if I did not want to show the progress output. thanks

Comment: Simply don't call the `redirectOutputStreamsToConsole` method or you could redirect to a different `PrintStream` such as a log file.

Answer (score 1):

It would be a good idea to include `pr.destroy()` at the end of your Java code so that it terminates the process when your program has ended. This solves error #1

What does `pr.exitValue()` return in these cases?

Comment: i will include pr.destroy() and i will do a run with pr.exitValue() and get back to you. thanks